User accessible directory that is guaranteed to be tmpfs?
As in the title, I'm looking for a user accessible directory that is guaranteed to be tmpfs.
/tmp is not even guaranteed to be wiped between reboots, so it's out.
/run is guaranteed to be tmpfs, and there is /run/user. Typically there is /run/user/$USER_ID under it. However, any documentation I find, has a note:

User code should not reference this directory directly, but via the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR environment variable, as documented in the XDG Base Directory Specification.

Meanwhile, the XDG Base Directory Specification does not give any guarantee that $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is tmpfs.
Is there any such directory that is guaranteed to be tmpfs and user accessible? Ideally, something based on a cross-distro spec like XDG or FHS, but distro specific info is helpful too.

Maybe you should check the requirements and reframe: why do you need tmpfs? Could you implement such requirements in an other way?

@GiacomoCatenazzi nope. Partially because it's a hypothetical, partially because the original context is improving IOPS over an NVMe drive without spending large amounts of money.

@jaskij Since a tmpfs file system can be swapped out, you cannot guarantee that its performance is any better than a mount on an NVMe disk.

So, why not tweaking the different cache and buffer parameters of the kernel? Or just memory mount a new disk. I'm worried by general requirement "user accessible": it may seem you want to hack an existing distribution (so doing unexpected things, which distribution is not configured to handle optimally, and other programs may do other hacks and so worsening all things. More hack you need, the more controlled/known system is required. Fair access to resources should be done cooperatively (not like many Windows programs which create mess and slow down things).

I can't think of anything except /dev/shm
